# Get the http post request body AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, post, request

I'm wondering how can I get the body of an HTTP POST request in AngularsJS.

The fact is that I have a website that post an http request to mywebsite with informations in the body that I want to get and treat in my angular app.

Is somebody has a solution to do that ? In angular I only succeeded to get the params of the request but not the body.

Thanks.

Comment: Some code would be very helpful: which website is posting to which and which one you are working on?

Comment: I would like to but in fact I do not control the website that send the request post. And in my angular app I have no code because it is what I'm looking for. I only can tell you that the website that send the request post (let's call it A) call one page in my angular app (let's call it B), and in my page (B) I would like to have the informations of the request post send by the other site (A). I hope it is clearer !

Answer (score 0):

You can print complete request and response in browser console.

```
angular.module('interceptors.httpInterceptors',[])

.factory('httpInterceptors', [function () {
  return {
    request: function (config) {
      console.log(angular.toJson(config));   
      return config;
    },
    response: function (response) {
      console.log(angular.toJson(response));
    },
    responseError: function(rejection) {
    }    

  };
}])

.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptors');
}]);
```

Comment: I already try this but in fact I receive only the information of the page I'm currently on. Instead I want the informations from the page that send the request post. I maybe forgot to say that the page that send the request post is not handled or created by me and is not angular.